# .net compact framework 2.0 text file reading

Tags: c#, .net, compact-framework2.0

I am working on a project where I have to read a text file and show only the lines that are between specific words. My current code is displaying all text in the file. I tried to use Linq but it failed or may be it is not supported by cf 2.0 at all.

## Example File Text:

*AAA_START:
This is a very big file that contains text but i only want to fetch the text that is between these two tags.
AAA_END.

BBB_START:
Text between these two tags or rest of the file must be ignored.
BB_END*

## Expected Output:

This is a very big file that contains text but i only want to fetch the text that is between these two tags.

Comment: Can you show your current code?

Comment: It seems you have a problem with your code. However, we can't help unless we have [code or information that can reproduce the problem](//stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Otherwise, we are just blindly guessing.